# Method to use IOCP to read file in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, iocp

I am coding using Python 3.5.

I want to use IOCP to read file in Windows. Is there any simple method to use ProactorEventLoop besides Subprocess or Executed Thread? Thanks!

Comment: Read tag-descriptions before adding.

Comment: Use the async module to read the file in main thread.  I am not sure that any method is 'simple'.